# Lebesgue points and convolution

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Here is the problem:

> Let $\phi=\phi(x)$ be a bounded measurable function in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq 1$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi=1$. Let $\phi_\varepsilon(x)=\varepsilon^{-d}\phi(x/\varepsilon)$, where $\varepsilon>0$. Define
>   $$
> f*\phi_\varepsilon(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-y)\phi_\varepsilon(y)dy.
> $$
>   Show that if $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, then
>   $$
> \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}f*\phi_\varepsilon(x)=f(x).
> $$
>   NOTE: We say $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$ if
>   $$
> \lim_{\substack{m(B)\to0\\B\ni x}}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)-f(x)|dy=0.
> $$

I am very stuck on this problem, and I am not sure where to begin. I am pretty sure the way to go about this is to show
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\;(f*\phi_\varepsilon(x)-f(x))=0,
$$
but I am not quite sure how to implement this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you just moved the $f$ on the left so this is equivalent ...
Since $∫ ϕ = 1$, you have $f(x) = ∫ f(x)\phi(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$. This might help.